# Crafting System not working in unity why?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I made a rudimentary crafting system but the crafting system is not working and I don't know why it doesn't work

```
public class CraftingItem: MonoBehaviour
{
  public int RequiredItems;
  public SCItem[] Item; 
  private GameObject player;
  private GameObject playerAction;
  public GameObject FinishItem;


  public void Start(){
    player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");
    playerAction = GameObject.FindWithTag("ItemManager");
  }

  public void CheckForRequiredItems(){
    int itemsInManager = playerAction.transform.childCount;

    if(itemsInManager > 0){
      int itemsFound = 0;
      for(int i = 0; i < RequiredItems; i++){
          
          for(int z = 0; z < itemsInManager; z++){
            
             if(playerAction.transform.GetChild(z).GetComponent<Item>() == Item[z]){
              itemsFound++;
              break;
          }
        }
      } 
      if(itemsFound >= RequiredItems){
        Instantiate(FinishItem, transform.position, transform.rotation);
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

unity inspector panel :[image]

I use a scriptable object to make the item, material, and attack items easy to control. Also, this script doesn't tell an error or syntax error, and I little bit confused. can you explain why and how can i fix this?

Comment: It seems you are following this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/j_tzaUMs45E?list=PLsMV160Duh4xlDF1GIlmtNE7YxwfyDzg3&t=1825)

Comment: -1 If you don't know what's going wrong; then what are you asking? Are you expecting someone to mentally step through the code? Do you know if the code even gets called? Did you debug anything? If there's no errors then at least tell us what does and does not happen.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet you wanted "i" there instead of "z" :)

```
if(playerAction.transform.GetChild(z).GetComponent<Item>() == Item[**i**]){
```

Comment: According to the tutorial, it's `GetChild(i)` and `Item[z]` but you are right it cannot be z both times! See timestamp: https://youtu.be/j_tzaUMs45E?list=PLsMV160Duh4xlDF1GIlmtNE7YxwfyDzg3&t=1825

Comment: So probably OP switched names because "z" value is looping over childCount. It's basicaly: 
`for(int z = 0; z < transform.childCount; z++) transform.GetChild(z);` I do not care about some tutorial in this example it looks like `GetChild(z)` and `Item[i]` is the correct answer.

Comment: I try it but it's not working, I try other things, and maybe I can try debugging